# Nested foreach loops - anything more efficient?

Tags: php, foreach

So I've got nested foreach loops, and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this, code-wise:

```
foreach ($arraykey as $columnname => $value) {
    foreach ($records as $field_entity_id) {    
        $fieldinsertloop = "('registration', 'reg_type', 0,".$field_entity_id.",".$field_entity_id.", 'und', 0,'".$value."','".$value."')";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " .str_replace("multi_reg", "field_data", $columnname);
    $sql .= " (entity_type, bundle, deleted, revision_id, entity_id, language, delta, ".str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname)."_value, ".str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname)."_format)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ";
    $sql .= $fieldinsertloop;
    db_query($sql);
}
```

Basically, I'm wanting to optimize for either speed and then less code written - in that order or optimally both.

Comment: Dude, you just removed the code and placed a TOTALLY different code - not cool!

Comment: And no, since there's no connection between the parameters of the nested `foreach` loops - it cannot be optimized.

Comment: I didn't know that was a faux pas. I grabbed the wrong chunk of code.

Comment: in any case, it looks like you're overwriting $fieldinsertloop during the second foreach...

Comment: @LS97 yes - that's the intention, to use the loop for multiple inserts.

Comment: In php there is a little to do to optimize your code, for that mysql query however, you could use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php On large number of inserts the improvement should be visible

Comment: @alfasin what's the point? isn't it just better to set it to the last value of the array instead of looping through and overwriting it, since you're not using any of its values except the last one?

Comment: Make `$fieldinsertloop` an array, add new value strings with `$fieldinsertloop[] = "(...)"` and do `$sql .= implode(",", $fieldinsertloop);` in the end. You current code will just insert ONE (1) line for each `$records` into your database, as @LS97 already said.

Comment: @LS97 it is being used at the end of the loop by calling `db_query()` - it's a drupal API call: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7

Comment: @alfasin No, I stand firm on the fact that in the code given above $fieldinsertloop is a string that gets overwritten completely during the looping of the $records array. Maybe, if the brackets had been placed differently, it would make a difference, like the answer below has inferred.

Comment: @LS97 you are right - he misplaced the closing bracket of the second `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can squeeze a bit more performance from your loops by using the values by reference:

```
foreach ($arraykey as $columnname => &$value) {
```

Hence the `&$value`, but beware, every time you do something to `$value` after that, it will affect the original `$arraykey[$columnname]` value. Also, not sure you're nesting the foreach correctly. I would move the ending bracket for the nested foreach down:

```
// $value passed by reference
foreach ($arraykey as $columnname => &$value) {

    // Pass $field_entity_id by reference
    foreach ($records as &$field_entity_id) {

        $fieldinsertloop = "('registration', 'reg_type', 0,".$field_entity_id.",".$field_entity_id.", 'und', 0,'".$value."','".$value."')";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO " .str_replace("multi_reg", "field_data", $columnname);
        $sql .= " (entity_type, bundle, deleted, revision_id, entity_id, language, delta, ".str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname)."_value, ".str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname)."_format)";
        $sql .= " VALUES ";
        $sql .= $fieldinsertloop;

        db_query($sql);

    } // End of nested foreach moved here
}
```

Another issue with your code, it appears you are using Drupal `db_query()` which has a much better way for inserting values. If you are, you could change your code to this:

```
foreach ($arraykey as $columnname => &$value) {

    $table = str_replace("multi_reg", "field_data", $columnname);
    $columns = array('entity_type', 'bundle', 'deleted', 'revision_id', 'entity_id', 'language', 'delta', str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname).'_value', str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname).'_format');

    foreach ($records as &$field_entity_id) {

        $values = array('registration', 'reg_type', 0, $field_entity_id, $field_entity_id, 'und', 0, $value, $value);

        //Build Associative Array for Insert
        for( $x = 0, $max = count($values); $x < $max; $x++ ) {
            $sqlValues[$columns[$x]] = $values[$x];
        }

        db_insert($table)->fields($columns)->values($sqlValues)->execute();
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
foreach ($arraykey as $columnname => &$value) {

    $table = str_replace("multi_reg", "field_data", $columnname);
    $columns = array('entity_type', 'bundle', 'deleted', 'revision_id', 'entity_id', 'language', 'delta', str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname).'_value', str_replace("multi_reg_", "", $columnname).'_format');
    $query = db_insert($table)->fields($columns);

    foreach ($records as &$field_entity_id) {

        $values = array('registration', 'reg_type', 0, $field_entity_id, $field_entity_id, 'und', 0, $value, $value);

        //Build Associative Array for Insert
        for( $x = 0, $max = count($values); $x < $max; $x++ ) {
            $sqlValues[$columns[$x]] = $values[$x];
        }

        $query->values($sqlValues);
    }
    $query->execute();
}
```

The second example should be faster, but with more lines. It waits until all the values have been added before executing. Using `db_insert()` requires that the values be in an associative array, with the column names as keys.

How's that for clean?